# Using Select for lattice points

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, filtering

I know how to use `Select` to generate a list of numbers which satisfy a certain condition. However, I am not sure how to do this for *points* (specifically 2-tuples) rather than numbers.

**What I am trying to do:** My function `f[a,b]` returns an integer polynomial in $x$. I want to plot the points $(r,t) \in \mathbb{N}^2$ such that `!IrreduciblePolynomialQ[f[r,t]]` returns `True`.

I think there is a crude way to do this by using both `Table` and `Select`, but surely there is a simpler way to use `Select` over the set of lattice points?

Comment: `Select[yourListOfPairs, Apply[Not[IrreduciblePolynomialQ[f[##]]]&]]`?